# React Hooks with SyntheticEvent , cant get value from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i'm a student trying to learn react typescript , and im having some problems

So i need to get value from a drop down list

Code:

```
var countryOptions = [
     { key: "al", value: "Albania", text: "Albania" },
     { key: "kos", value: "Kosovo", text: "Kosovo" },
];


<Dropdown   
    clearable
    fluid
    multiple
    search
    selection
    options={qytetetOptions}
    value={adresa.qyteti}
/>
```

the way we learned is to use react hooks this way:

```
const initializeForm = () => {
    return {
      id: "",
      emri: "",
      mbiemri: "",
      nrTelefonit: "",
      nrTelefonit2: "",
      adrersa: "",
      adresa2: "",
      qyteti: "",
      shteti: "",
    };
  };
const [adresa, setAdresaF] = useState<IAdresaF>(initializeForm);




const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setAdresaF({ ...adresa, [name]: value });
};
```

But this is for form inputs , in drop down list it saysthat i need to use SythneticEvent

Can somebody help how to get value from drop down list

Comment: What UI library is your `Dropdown` component from?

Comment: Its from semantic-ui-react

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI React's [`Dropdown`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-controlled) component accepts `onChange` prop you can assign your handler to. So your code for updating state from `Dropdown` component may look like:

```ts
const [adresa, setAdresaF] = useState<IAdresaF>(initializeForm)

const handleQutetyChange = (
    ev: React.SyntheticEvent,
    { value }: any
) => {
    setAdresaF({ ...adresa, qutety: value })
}

...

return (
    ...
    <Dropdown
        onChange={handleQutetyChange}
        ...
        value={adresa.qutety}
    />
    ...
)
```

Unfortunately you'll have to type the second parameter as `any`. [Type definition](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/abaf123cdd0dacaa260ecdd1920a3383baa2ba4e/src/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.d.ts#L146) of `onChange` function is overly vague.

```ts
export interface DropdownProps extends StrictDropdownProps {
  [key: string]: any
}

...
onChange?: (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data: DropdownProps) => void
```

Though you make take a longer route. Type it as `unknown` and then narrow the type properly. With [custom type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for example. Though as long as your options are all known beforehand and cannot change in runtime I believe that's unnecessary step.

Comment: Thank u brother  , it worked , we learned that typescript is strictly typing and we need to specify the type , but it worked with any so thank u again